# Moving values from one index to another within the same array, possible?

Tags: c#

This is for a school assignment.

Myself and my group partner are wondering if it's possible to move a value to another index
within the same array ?

Comment: did you try anything?

Answer (score 4):

Sure.

```
var temp = array[i];
array[i] = array[j];
array[j] = temp;
```

Comment: Well, that'd swap it, but the question is so vague, that it sounds to me like a remove and insert would be better...

Comment: Arrays are usually considered fixed size. Therefore swapping seems to me to be as close as you can get to moving items in an array.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can;

```
var array= new int[]{1, 2, 3};
foreach (var i in array)
{
    Console.WriteLine (i);
}

array[1] = array[2];

foreach (var j in array)
{
    Console.WriteLine (j);
}
```

Results will be;

```
1 2 3
1 3 3
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/MRw0rs).

But of course, this will coping value from one value to another one. Old index value is moved to new index value. If you want to use change their values, you can use a `temp` value like [Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14790902/447156).

Answer (score 1):

Moving a value in C# is very different from moving, say, an orange from your fridge to your table, in the sense that when you move the orange from one place to another, the old place no longer contains the orange.

Moving an item in the array, on the other hand, is, essentially, an act of copying<sup>*</sup>, so you can write something like this:

```
myArray[newIndex] = myArray[oldIndex];
```

Now the item from the old index is moved to its new index. The old index contains the item as well. If you do not want that to happen, you need to explicitly "remove" the item by replacing it with something else. In an array of reference objects you replace it with `null`:

```
myArray[oldIndex] = null;
```

In an array of value objects, you replace it with some special value that you designate as "nothing", or with `null` if your value object is nullable.

---

<sup>*</sup> What you copy depends on the type of the array element: in an array of value types, the item itself gets copied; in an array of reference types, a reference gets copied. Continuing with the orange analogy, when orange is a reference type, an array of oranges is a list of post-it notes defining the locations of all oranges in the array. Instead of moving an orange into the array, you put a post-it note that says "third orange from the right", and leave the orange in place. Copying a reference object simply copies its post-it note.

Comment: +1 just for your effort and beautiful analyzing.

Answer (score 0):

Copy is simply

```
array[Index+1] = array[Index]
```

Swap is

```
var tmp = array[Index + 1];
array[Index+1] = arry[Index];
array[Index] = tmp;
```

Move well depends on what you want to replace the moved item with to indicate it's now empty, something like

```
array[Index+1] = array[Index];
array[Index] = -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of an array as a stacker trays. things can be in them, and you can move stuff around, but putting things into one drawer or another won't affect the order of anything else.

Rather than using an array, you could use a list

```
        List<int> myList = new List<int>();
        myList.Add(1);
        myList.Add(2);
        myList.Add(3);
        myList.Add(4);
        myList.Add(5);
```

will give you 1,2,3,4,5.

then calling

```
    int temp = myList[1];
    myList.RemoveAt(1);
    myList.Insert(3, temp);
```

will give you 1,3,4,2,5